# Trying to generate a unique id for every item in my array

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Im trying to pass in a unique id for every item that is added to cart. currently I have it working to adjust quantity and based on that the correct numbers of items are added to the cart. But lets say I have two of one item. Those two items are given the same id. Is there anyway to give them a unique id? Mainly for removing purposes.

current adding to cart function

```
 const updateCart = () => {
    itemToSend.forEach(element => {
      addToCart(element);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use index of foreach function :

```
const updateCart = () => {
    itemToSend.forEach((element, index) => {
      addToCart(element, index);
    });
  };
```

and as better solution use .map method of es6 :

```
  const updateCart = () => {
    itemToSend.map((element, index) => {
      addToCart(element, index);
    });
  };
```

and then use this unique index as id like below with combination of  string:

```
<p id= {"element" + id }></p>
```

with this approach there is no need to add new library to your project

Answer (score 2):

You can use `uuid` library to generate unique id

Comment: Should've added this in the original q. Im using uuid. The problem is that if the quantity is greater than 1, all items of the same value have the same id. so someone choosing Steak for example. if they pick quantity 2 they both have the same id. which turns into an issue when trying to remove one item. they both get removed since both have the same id.

Comment: You can try ```addToCart({ ...element, removeId: uuid.v4() });```

Comment: You also can use item's index in array to remove it

Comment: Thanks a bunch. been tinkering for hours now. Perfect